# Null model for cross-correlation

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, cross-correlation

I have two time series $X_t$ and $Y_t$ .
The cross-correlation at lag $\tau$ is defined as

$$
C(\tau) = \frac{\langle X_t \; Y_{t-\tau}\rangle - \langle X_t \rangle \langle Y_{t-\tau} \rangle }{\sigma_X \sigma_{Y}}.
$$

I want to compute a null model for $C(\tau)$ at each lag $\tau$.

For normal correlation ($\tau = 0$) I would generate many times the surrogate series $\tilde{X_t}$ and $\tilde{Y_t}$  by shuffling the original series and then computing the null model $\tilde{C} = \frac{\langle \tilde{X_t} \; \tilde{Y_t}\rangle - \langle \tilde{X_t} \rangle \langle \tilde{Y_t} \rangle }{\sigma_X \sigma_{Y}}$ .

For cross correlation I could do the same but I have two problems:

1. Shuffling destroy 0 lag correlation but I'm not sure what happen at different lags. So is this really a good null model when $\tau\neq0$ ?
2. Since I am testing multiple lags, do I have to correct for the [multiple comparison problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem)?

Comment: You can employ a standard test for the correlation coefficient: search our site for "Fisher's transformation."  Yes, there is a multiple comparisons problem, but it's difficult to correct for it because the tests are not independent.  People therefore usually do not conduct omnibus tests of all lags, but (a) focus on those of interest and (b) use approximations.